# CORS issue with webroute in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, apache

I try my laravel project in apache server

I clone my project

```
sudo -u www-data git clone ******* laravel
```

Lunch composer

```
sudo -u www-data composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

Lunch npm and webpack

```
sudo -u www-data npm install
sudo -u www-data npm run production
```

Create .env

```
sudo -u www-data cp .env.example .env
```

Generate key

```
sudo -u www-data php artisan key:generate
sudo -u www-data php artisan config:cache
```

After clone my project and installed all packages, i configure .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
Alias /laravel /var/www/html/laravel/public/
<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

But i have a 500 error when i try to login.
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have an explanation to this ?

[UPDATE 1]

I forgot to do this :

```
sudo -u www-data php artisan passport:install
```

But now all my web routes have this error

[image]

[UPDATE 2]

All my web routes have 127.0.0.1:8000. But i'm in production, i shouldn't have this, no ?

[UPDATE 3]

I has installed fruitcake/laravel-cors

```
sudo composer remove barryvdh/laravel-cors fruitcake/laravel-cors
sudo -u www-data composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

I allow CORS for all your routes in app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
  \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    // ...
]
```

I reload my Laravel configurations and allow my changes to reflect

```
sudo -u www-data php artisan config:cache
```

For mapApiRoutes it's work, but not for mapWebRoutes. How can i fix for mapWebRoutes ?

Comment: It's 'Server Error'

Comment: i edit the post. i add a picture

Comment: I add a another picture

Comment: It isn't clear from the question - does your site work at all?  Or it is just login that fails?  What do PHP and Apache and Laravel logs show?

Comment: @KamleshPaul i have this message now : Key path "file:///var/www/html/laravel/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks you ! but now i have another error. I edit my post with new picture

Comment: it is showing 200 what is error ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul the response is empty. But in access.log i have this message "server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name"

Comment: that i ssl issue may be then

Comment: @KamleshPaul All my web routes have 127.0.0.1:8000. But i'm in production, i shouldn't have this, no ? (i realise a spa app with vue.js)

Comment: yes for production you need to use ip or domain name

Comment: @KamleshPaul in .env i change APP_URL, add MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}". Change 'url' in config/app.php and run sudo -u www-data npm run production, nevertheless it's keep 127.0.0.1. (i also restart the server apache) is there a step i forgot ?

Comment: is it local or server?

Comment: It's server, not local

Comment: @KamleshPaul i try to installed fruitcake/laravel-cors, but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was so stupid ...

In my component, l had this

```
created() {
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasksList')
                .then(response => this.tasks = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
```

BUT, in my .env, i have

```
APP_URL=http://*****.*****.***:8080
```

I corrected my component

```
created() {
            axios.get('/tasksList')
                .then(response => this.tasks = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
```

NOW it's work.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
allow from all
```

... is Apache 2.2 syntax.  In Apache 2.4, use:

```
Require all granted
```

[Info in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

Answer (score 0):

No need of both Allow and Require i guess, but i am using similar config in all projects and it's working

<Directory /var/www/html/laravel/public>
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Require all granted

Comment: From [the docs I linked to in my answer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html): *Mixing old directives like Order, Allow or Deny with new ones like Require is technically possible but discouraged.*